# butterknife 8.8.1 error ';' excpect

Tags: butterknife

I have got a error `';' expectd`, and checked the log record `Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]` found in eventlog, finally it showed me `Gradle build finished with 1 error(s)`.

I have no idea to solve the problem, please help me. Thank you~

**Error Infomation**

```
[Messages window]
Error:(56, 53) Error: ';' expectd
Information:BUILD FAILED in 0s
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

[EventLog window]

```
17:14   Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
17:15   Gradle build finished with 1 error(s) in 506ms
```

**Global build.gradle **

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:8.8.1'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Module build.gradle **

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.butterknife' 

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.test.www"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    //butterknife
    javaCompileOptions { annotationProcessorOptions { includeCompileClasspath = true } }

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    //butterknife
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
}
```

** layout  activity_main.xml **

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.test.www.activity.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnOpen"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Open"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnClose"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Close"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

** MainActivity **

```
package com.test.www.activity;

import android.arch.lifecycle.OnLifecycleEvent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.yanhui.www.switchlamp.R;
import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import butterknife.OnClick;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String IDENTITY_TAG = "MainActivity";

    @BindView(R.id.btnOpen)
    Button btnOpen;
    @BindView(R.id.btnClose)
    Button btnClose;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        @OnClick (R.id.btnOpen) public void startSomething() {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "startSomething", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @OnClick (R.id.btnClose) public void endSomething() {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "endSomething", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

It could not pass the assembleDebug, showed the error `';' expected`. @BindView was okay, but @OnClick made the misstake that I didn't find the method to solve it.

Comment: The error happen in which line of code?

Comment: This Line： @OnClick (R.id.btnOpen)

Comment: Try to remove the space between `@OnClick` and `(R...)`

Comment: same error when the space have been removed

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined functions inside `onCreate()` callback of `MainActivity`. Try to move them out like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String IDENTITY_TAG = "MainActivity";

    @BindView(R.id.btnOpen)
    Button btnOpen;
    @BindView(R.id.btnClose)
    Button btnClose;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.btnOpen) 
    public void startSomething() {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "startSomething", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.btnClose) 
    public void endSomething() {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "endSomething", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: 666~  Thank you very much~

Comment: @yan btw, happy coding!